# Can't submit the form after validating with jquery (using preventDefault())

Tags: jquery, validation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#addprojectform').live('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     $(".error").remove();   

    var startdate = $("#startdate").val();
    var client = $('#client').val();
    var source_lang= $('#source_lang option:selected').length;
    var targ_lang = $('#targ_lang option:selected').length;
    var qty = $('#qty').val();

    var hasError = false;

   if(startdate == '') {
  $("#startdate").after('<span class="error" style="color: red;">This field is     required.</span>');
  hasError = true;
}

if(client == '') {
  $("#client").after('<span class="error" style="color: red;">This field is required.  </span>');
  hasError = true;
}

if(!(source_lang)) {
  $("#source_lang").after('<span class="error" style="color: red;">This field is required.</span>');
  hasError = true;
}

if(!(targ_lang)) {
  $("#targ_lang").after('<span class="error" style="color: red;">This field is required.</span>');
  hasError = true;
}
if(qty == '') {
  $("#qty").after('<span class="error"  style="color: red;">This field is required.</span>');
  hasError = true;
}
} // if translation


if(hasError == false)
 return true;
    });

 });
 </script>
```

I had this code. I want to validate the form before submission. I can't control when the form has no errors. I want to submit the form if there are no errors found. I added this code:

```
if(hasError == false)
 return true;
```

but doesn't submit the form.. Please anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove

```
e.preventDefault();
```

and change

```
if(hasError == false)
   return true;
});
```

into

```
return !hasError;
```

as a side note, `live()` is deprecated in favour of `on()` on newer jQuery version

Answer (score 1):

What I do, although it may not be fantastic is:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) 
{
    if(!$(this).hasClass('valid'))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var isValid = false;
        // do validation to set isValid true or false;
        if(isValid)
        {
            $(this).addClass('valid');
            $(this).submit();
            // or possibly $(this).addClass('valid').submit();
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

How this works is, first time you submit, it checks to see if the form has a class called `valid`. If not, it stops the form validation and does validation.

If it's valid, it will add the class to the form and resubmit. As the form now has the `valid` class, it will bypass validation and submit normally.